# twitter api update status updating but no response from twitter

Tags: php, codeigniter, twitter

having a bit of an issue with the twitter API. When I send something to https://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/update.json, the tweet (status update) does get sent, however, I do not get a response from twitter. When I send requests to any of the other api urls they work as expected and do return a response. Please see code below...

```
function postStatus($oauthToken,$status) {

    //Create sig base string
    $tokenddata = array('oauth_token'=>$oauthToken['oauth_token'],'oauth_token_secret'=>$oauthToken['oauth_token_secret']);
    $status = rawurlencode($status);
    $baseurl = $this->baseurl . "statuses/update.json";
    $url = "{$baseurl}?status={$status}";
    $authHeader = get_auth_header($url, $this->_consumer['key'], $this->_consumer['secret'],
                            $tokenddata, 'POST', $this->_consumer['algorithm']);
    $postfields = "status={$status}";
    $response = $this->_connect($url,$authHeader,$postfields,'POST');
    return json_decode($response);
}

private function _connect($url, $auth, $postfields=null, $method='GET') {
    $ch = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC ) ;
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION,3);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array($auth));
    if ($method == 'POST') {
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);
        if (!empty($postfields)) {
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postfields);
        }
    }

    $curl_info = curl_getinfo($ch);
    $response = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    return $response;
}
```

And as I said before, the other requests that I am using are 'GET' requests and use the code below...

```
function getFromTwitter($url, $oauthToken, $params=null) {
    $tokenddata = array('oauth_token'=>$oauthToken['oauth_token'],'oauth_token_secret'=>$oauthToken['oauth_token_secret']);
    $baseurl = $this->baseurl . $url;
    if(!empty($params)) {
        $fullurl = $baseurl . "?" . build_http_query($params);
        $postfields = build_http_query($params);
        $authHeader = get_auth_header($fullurl, $this->_consumer['key'], $this->_consumer['secret'],
                            $tokenddata, 'GET', $this->_consumer['algorithm']);
    } else {
        $authHeader = get_auth_header($baseurl, $this->_consumer['key'], $this->_consumer['secret'],
                            $tokenddata, 'GET', $this->_consumer['algorithm']);
    }
    if(!empty($postfields)) {
        $response = $this->_connect($fullurl,$authHeader);
    } else {
        $response = $this->_connect($baseurl,$authHeader);
    }
    return json_decode($response);
}
```

Thanks for all of the help! 
-SM

Answer (score 0):

Implementing code for social networks on your own can be a pain (in my opinion)

It would be easier for you to use twitter-async (https://github.com/jmathai/twitter-async)

I have added it before to my CI as a helper function then used it as is.

It was easy to use & well documented.

Comment: Ahmad, I am using the library that was created by abraham, modified for use with CIs MVC architecture. All was working correctly until twitter changed to api v1.1. The only thing that is not working now is getting the response from twitter.